# The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm trying to add functionality to a C# Web API to write data into a log table, when a user attempts to log in.  I'm still fairly new to Entity Framework, and find it straightforward for reading out data, but I'm getting stuck on one point.

**AppDbContext.cs**

```
namespace IGpay.Context
{
    public class AppDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext()
        {
        }

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options):base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LoginModel> Login { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PaymentRequestModel> PaymentRequests { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PaymentModel> PaymentResults { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChildClientsModel> ChildClients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OpenBankingDataModel> OBNetworkRequest { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OBPaymentStatusCheckResponseCodes> DescriptionFromTransactionStatus { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OBPaymentStatusCheckResponseCodes> DescriptionFromReasonCode { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LoginActivityModel> LoginActivity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UserController.cs**

```
namespace IGpay.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;
        public UserController(AppDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            _db = appDbContext;
        }
        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] UserModel userObj)
        {
        LoginActivityModel login = new LoginActivityModel();
        var user = await _db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EmailId == userObj.EmailId);
        if (user == null)
        {
             login.LoginStatus = "Failed";
             login.isLockedAccount = false;
             login.Details = "No email address found";
             login.UserID = 0;
             InsertLoginActivity(login); <--- THIS INSERT FAILS
        }
        else
        {
             login.LoginStatus = "Success";
             login.isLockedAccount = user.IsAccountLocked;
             login.Details = "Login successful";
             login.UserID = user.Id;
             InsertLoginActivity(login); <--- THIS INSERTS
             return Ok(new
             {
                   Message = "Log in successful",
                   Token = token,
                   Status = true,
                   UserID = user.Id
             });
         }
    }
    public void InsertLoginActivity(LoginActivityModel login)
    {
        _db.LoginActivity.Add(login);
        try
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The above is a cut down version of my code, but I return the single row from the Users table, but if there is no data (user == null), then I want to insert a record into another table - which is LoginActivity, if there is data returned from Users - this won't error.

The error returned is:

> System.Exception: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I have had a read up on the documentation, but can't see anything that will resolve my issue.  I built the code using a YouTube tutorial for creating a log in system, so have used that to learn Entity Framework.  A lot of the solutions to the optimistic concurrency exception use the `using()` block - which I haven't here (as it wasn't included in the tutorial).

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?  I have had several attempts at trying to resolve this unsuccessfully.

I have attempted different methods of resolving this issue, but can't find a solid resolution.

Comment: What is `login` inside the shown code? Field? How and where it is initialized? It really has to be variable or `new`-ed before calling insert.

Comment: Sorry I left that element out - I have included it now, initiating a new instance of `LoginActivityModel`

Comment: I have expanded my code block to show a little more detail and what works and doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, what is the type of `login.UserID` property/column? Is it nullable or not? Is it FK to other table? Can you do `login.UserID = null;` instead of `login.UserID = 0;` in the problematic code branch?

Comment: Can you post the code related to your dbcontext and from your startup class?

Comment: @IvanStoev login.UserID is an integer, this is set as an output when no records are returned (the email address doesn't exist) - this is a NULLABLE column, but my model only allows for an integer.  Changing this to null fails validation (and code won't run)

Comment: @topsail I have updated my original post with the AppDbContext class

Comment: And the code from your startup class where you add the the dbcontext to your application (if this is the right word) ... my thought is that you don't have the right lifetime/scoping for your dbcontext. It should be short lived, per request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/ (though admittedly, it seems like what you have done is correct, so it's not clear why it appears to have been affected by other changes). Might be something about this asynsc usage here too ...

Comment: *"this is a NULLABLE column, but my model only allows for an integer"* This is *not* ok. The model and database must match, especially the nullability. Change the property type in the model to be `int?` (`Nullable<int>`). This is a *must*. Not sure what "validation" fails, but whatever it is, it should be corrected as well. `0` cannot be used as `null` replacement, especially in relation database enforced FK constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @IvanStoev for the solution to this problem - I've not been scaffolding my database structure automatically and have created the table models myself - and quite rightly pointed out that if my table columns can be null, my model must also contain nullable properties.

**Before**

```
namespace IGpay.Models
{
    public class LoginActivityModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string LoginStatus { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public bool isLockedAccount { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public string Event { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

**After**

```
namespace IGpay.Models
{
    public class LoginActivityModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int? UserID { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? LoginStatus { get; set; }
        public string? IP { get; set; }
        public bool? isLockedAccount { get; set; }
        public string? Details { get; set; }
        public string? Event { get; set; }        
    }
}
```